# Showing Header of Tab using Prism

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using Prism and have a region that is a TabControl. I have a DataTemplate on the TabControl.ItemTemplate set to an interface of type IView. IView has a Title and Description string. When I call RegisterViewWithRegion with my IView, the tab is added but no description is shown on the header. Can I not bind to properties on an interface or am I missing something else?

manager.AddToRegion("ContentZone", new PrimaryView()); //Implements IView

```
<TabControl x:Name="ContentZone" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentZone" Grid.Row="1" umn="0">
<TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type oasis:IView}">
        <DockPanel ToolTip="{Binding Path=Description}">
            <Label Padding="0"
                   Content="{Binding Path=Title}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Edit: I found a solution, although I don't find it all that great. For some reason the DataContext of the DataTemplate was always coming back as null no matter what I did, I tried the DataTempalteSelector, but the item itself was also null. I tried changing to a base abstract class instead, and nor did that work. So this is what I ended up with for the binding itself:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}, Path=DataContext.Title}
```

Comment: Souldn't you be using TabItem.HeaderTemplate?

Comment: Wow, have no idea, have long, long since moved on from Prism, is it still even maintained?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot associate a `DataTemplate` with an interface. It must be directly associated with the type. If you want to associate via an interface, you could consider implementing a `DataTemplateSelector` that checks whether the item implements `IView` and returns a `DataTemplate` accordingly.

Comment: So I gave that a shot, but the item being returned in the SelectTemplate method always is null. I registered it like below. The breakpoint hits, but item is null.

<OasisShell:TabTemplateSelector
    x:Key="TabTemplateSelector"                 
    IViewTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}" />